# how to run 2 commands after failure in a loop?

Tags: command-line, bash

I want to write a simple loop like this:

```
for f in my_file0 my_file1 my_file2; do
    (( $(find . -name $f | wc -l > 0 ))
done
```

However, I want the loop to break the script if fails and print an error message, so I did this:

```
for f in my_file0 my_file1 my_file2; do
    (( $(find . -name $f | wc -l > 0 )) || echo error && exit 1
done
```

which exits at the first iteration, obviously.

So, I moved on to this solution

```
for f in my_file0 my_file1 my_file2; do
    (( $(find . -name $f | wc -l > 0 )) || (echo error && exit 1)
done
```

which, as I understand it, only exits the sub-shell :-(

So, now I write it like this:

```
for f in my_file0 my_file1 my_file2; do
    (( $(find . -name $f | wc -l > 0 ))
    if (( $? > 0 )); then echo error && exit 1; fi
done
```

but that sucks...

What can I do, beside calling a function that will run those two commands?

Comment: Use `break` in place of `exit 1`? This way you'll get out of for loop but not subshell.

Comment: Please tell us what you try to ... Read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Also, please check your syntax... I'd say you're missing a closing bracket after each `| wc -l`. And generally speaking: a `find | wc -l` in a `for f in files*` loop is a good solution for exactly nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use curly braces instead of parentheses, that one doesn't spawn a new subshell:

```
... || { echo error; exit 1; }
```

Notice that – unlike with parentheses – you'll need to put a semicolon even after the last statement.

Also note that I've changed `&&` into a `;`, I think you should even exit if `echo` fails for whatever unlikely reason; feel free to change that back if you really wish to continue the loop if `echo` fails.